# Why does "this" change when passing a function as a call back?

Tags: javascript

I have these 2 objects:

```
var Foo = function () {
    this.name = 'foo';
};

Foo.prototype.sayName = function () {
    console.log(this.name);
};
```

```
var Bar = function () {
    this.cb = null;
};

Bar.prototype.setCb = function (cb) {
    this.cb = cb;
};

Bar.prototype.callCb = function () {
    this.cb();
};
```

And I have this result:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();

foo.sayName();  // "foo"
bar.setCb(foo.sayName);
bar.callCb();   // undefined
```

This happens because when we call `foo.sayName` inside `Bar`, `this` is pointing to the `Bar` object. Can someone explain what's happening here?

I also noticed that I can circumvent this by instead passing in an anonymous function `bar.setCb(function() {foo.sayName();});`. Are there other/better ways around this problem?

Comment: Use `() => foo.sayName()` instead of `foo.sayName` (a shorter form of what you already discovered). The explanation is: `this` is bound at the call site, and the function is called as `this.cb()` and not `foo.sayName()`. Another solution would be to pass `foo.sayName.bind(foo)` but I think an arrow function is much more readable.

Comment: You're passing in the _result_ of _calling_ `sayName` but `callCb` is expecting a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the part of Javascript that most throws people coming from another language.

Basically, the `this` pointer is set at the time of the call. When you pull a function off an object, you just get the function, not the context in which it came from (the object it came from). This is unlike for example Python with its bound method objects.

In fact, if you did something like:

```
let sayName = foo.sayName
sayName()
```

that would also throw with an "undefined" exception, since calling it that way you lose which object you're calling the method on.

So how do you work around this? There's a couple of options, both of which involve capturing that context.

The first you can do, as the comment suggested, would be to use an arrow function:

```
bar.setCb(() => foo.sayName())
```

This "captures" the object to call the function on.

Another option would be to use the `Function.bind` function:

```
bar.setCb(foo.sayName.bind(foo))
```

This creates a new function instance that has it's `this` pointer set to foo.